# Array outputting as object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Sorry if I've explained this wrong but I've got an object which is an array and I'm trying to get the fields to output but all I'm getting is [object object]

```
$.getJSON( "https://service1.homepro.com/smart.asmx/GetFAP_ProfileReviewsJSON?bid=141772&sort=1&page=1", function( data ) {
        // console.log(data);
        xmlText = data;
        var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( xmlText );
        // console.log(jsonObj.SMART);

        var html = '<div class="review">';
        $.each( jsonObj, function( key, answer ) {
        // console.log('key', key);
        console.log('answer', answer);

        html += '<div>' + answer + '</div>';
        // html += '<div>' + key + '</div>';
    });

    $('div').html(html);
});
```

Can anyone help or show me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: definitely add javascript tag.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting object Object? you're being a bit unclear.

Comment: Need to see `x2js.xml_str2json()` because the return on that function (or method) is probably the issue.

Comment: try `console.log('answer', JSON.stringify(answer));` and see if that gives you better results

Comment: `[object Object]` is the standard `toString` for an object in javascript. So `answer` is an object.

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects. Access the properties whose values you want to show instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
$.getJSON( "https://service1.homepro.com/smart.asmx/GetFAP_ProfileReviewsJSON?bid=141772&sort=1&page=1", function( data ) {
  var xmlText = data,
      x2js = new X2JS(),
      jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( xmlText ),
      html = '<div class="review">';

      $.each( jsonObj.SMART.XMLJSON, function( key, answer ) {
        html += '<div><strong>' + answer.RefName + '</strong> - ' + answer.Testimonial + '</div>';
      });

  $('body').html(html);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x2js/1.2.0/xml2json.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have to iterate through `jsonObj.SMART.XMLJSON`, not `jsonObj`.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript `[object object]` is the default string representation of a JavaScript `object` if it isn't `null` or `undefined`, you can see in the [**JavaScript toString() Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) that:

> Every object has a `toString()` method **that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected**. By default, the `toString()` method is inherited by every object descended from `Object`. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, `toString()` returns "`[object type]`", where type is the object type. The following code illustrates this:

```
var o = new Object();
o.toString(); // returns [object Object]
```

> **Note:**
>   Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns [object
>   Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in the 5th
>   Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata. See
>   Using_toString()_to_detect_object_class.

**Solution:**

- If you want to print your `object` you need to write a custom
  function that will do it for you by producing a custom representation
  of your object based on its properties.
- You can also use `JSON.stringify(answer)` it will return your object
  as a string but I don't think it will give you the output you want to
  see.